# Python Curve Fitting issue

Tags: python, numpy

EDIT: First problem solved but I now have a new issue:

I am currently doing a curve fit on some data to be input. My function is:

```
def extract_parameters(Ts, ts):
    def model(t, Ti, Ta, c):
        return (Ti - Ta)*math.e**(-t / c) + Ta
    popt, pcov = cf(model, ts, Ts, p0 = (10, 7, 6))
    Ti, Ta, c = popt
    xfine = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
    yfitted = model(xfine, *popt)
    pl.plot(Ts, ts, 'o', label = 'data point')
    pl.plot(xfine, yfitted, label = 'fit')
    pylab.legend()
    pylab.show()
```

When I enter:

```
extract_parameters(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]), np.array([10.0,9.0,8.5,8.0,7.5,7.3,7.0,6.8,6.6,6.3]))
```

My graph starts to fit right at the end but while my data starts at 10 my curve starts at about 240 and then sweeps dow, which is not what I want. I thought setting p0 would help but it doesn't appear to help at all.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters to fit are `Ti`, `Ta` and `c`, so don't define `Ti` first:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def model(t, Ti, Ta, c):
    return (Ti - Ta) * np.exp(-t / c) + Ta

Ti, Ta, c = 100, 25, 10     # super-low heat-capacity tea!
t = np.linspace(0,100,101)  # time grid
data = model(t, Ti, Ta, c)  # the data to be fitted
data += np.random.rand(len(data))    # add some noise
curve_fit(model, t, data)
```

gives:

```
(array([ 100.4656674 ,   25.44794971,   10.04560802]),
 array([[ 0.02530277,  0.00100244, -0.00377959],
        [ 0.00100244,  0.00122549, -0.00062579],
        [-0.00377959, -0.00062579,  0.00128791]]))
```

Comment: Thank you, that problem is now solved. Could you please help with my new one?

Comment: @GBA13: If xnx's answer helped you solve the first problem, please accept his answer and then open a new question. It's not really fair to keep moving the goal post :)

Comment: OK, will do. It just won't let me post again for a while so I thought I'd try here.